# Best way to check whether a vector permutation has every element in a new position

Tags: r

I want to check whether a vector permutation is unique. For example, I have the vector c(1, 2, 3, 4). Say I do `sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4))`, and the result is 4 3 2 1. This permutation is unique, since every element is in a new position. Now, I can do this for these type of vectors using `which()` statements, but this doesn't work for the vector `c(1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1)`, because it always says nothing has changed after mixing it up. What's the best way of doing this?

I've tried using `match()` and `which()` statements:

```
if (length(which(n == sample(n))) == 0) { 'unique' }
```

Comment: `identical(n, sample(n))`? its not entirely clear though to me from your example.

Comment: I want to check that my permuted vector has every element in a different place than my original vector (so a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) and sample(a) == c(4, 3, 2, 1) should return true, since every element is in a new position

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work also for vectors that have repeated elements (e.g. `c(1,1,1,1)`) you need to be tracking the index of the observation when you take the sample. E.g. you could do it with the simple function below that samples by position and compares positions:

```r
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
unique_sample <- function(x) {
  samp <- sample(length(x))
  ident <- !any(samp == (1:length(x)))
  list(unique = ident, draw = x[samp])
}
set.seed(42)
unique_sample(a)
#> $unique
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $draw
#> [1] 3 2 1 2 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most intuitive way would be to loop over your sampled vectors, and use the function `all` to check if all elements in the sampled vector are equal to your original vector's elements. You can always flip it around using `!`, to obtain non-equal vectors. Like so:

```
set.seed(12345)
original <- 1:4
samples <- replicate(n=20, expr = { sample(original) })

#> samples
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
#[1,]    3    2    3    3    2    2    3    1    1     4     4     2     1     2     3     4     4     3     2     4
#[2,]    4    1    4    1    4    1    2    2    3     3     2     1     2     1     1     1     1     4     4     2
#[3,]    2    3    1    4    1    4    4    3    4     2     3     3     3     4     4     2     2     2     1     3
#[4,]    1    4    2    2    3    3    1    4    2     1     1     4     4     3     2     3     3     1     3     1

## I presume you want to find indices where vectors such as 8th and 13th occur (or the inverse)

indices <- apply(samples, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(z) { all(z==original) })

#> which(indices)
#[1]  8 13
#> samples[,which(indices)]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    3    3
#[4,]    4    4

## Conversely, if you only want vectors that are different from the original one, use:
# which(!indices)
```

I'm not sure if this is the most computationally efficient way to do it, but it's at least pretty simple and uses only base R.

EDIT: Notice that this will not be able to distinguish between positions from the original vector, as `all(x==y)` only compares the exact contents in a pair-wise manner between the vectors `x` and `y`. It works fine if all your original elements are unique, but won't be able to able to distinguish between duplicates and their respective positions.

EDIT2: Alternative, if the original positions matter in respect to duplicates, you could sample element indices instead of element content. It's probably more memory efficient too, depending on your actual elements' class type:

```
set.seed(12345)
original <- c("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar")
samples <- replicate(n=20, expr = { sample(1:length(original)) })
indices <- apply(samples, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(z) { all(z==1:length(original)) })

# To obtain the unique sampled vectors where original positions matter
#> do.call("cbind", lapply(which(!indices), FUN=function(z) { original[samples[,z]] }))
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
#[1,] "bar" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "foo" "bar" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "foo" "bar"
#[2,] "bar" "foo" "bar" "foo" "bar" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo"
#[3,] "foo" "bar" "foo" "bar" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar" "foo" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "bar"
#[4,] "foo" "bar" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo" "bar" "foo"
## Notice that columns 2, 6, 11, and 12 are included because duplicates have changed places.

# To obtain the sampled vectors that were identical also in respect to position indices
#> do.call("cbind", lapply(which(indices), FUN=function(z) { original[samples[,z]] }))
#     [,1]  [,2] 
#[1,] "foo" "foo"
#[2,] "foo" "foo"
#[3,] "bar" "bar"
#[4,] "bar" "bar"
```